# Redirecting internal traffic to gateway's port-forwarded external endpoints directly to intranet destination

Tags: routing, iptables

There's an intranet and CentOS-powered gateway that provides connectivity for intranet devices.

Typical port-forwarding in gateway's iptables ruleset looks like this (TCP version is provided):

```
$IPTABLES -A PREROUTING -t nat -i $EXTERNAL_IF -p tcp -d $EXTERNAL_IP \
    --dport $EXTERNALPORT -j DNAT --to $INTERNAL_IP:$INTERNAL_PORT
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $EXTERNAL_IF -p tcp -d $INTERNAL_IP \
    --dport $INTERNAL_PORT -j ACCEPT
```

The $EXTERNAL_IP:$EXTERNAL_PORT is inaccessible from intranet in such configuration.

Is there way to redirect all internal (originating from intranet) traffic to $EXTERNAL_IP:$EXTERNAL_PORT directly to $INTERNAL_IP:$INTERNAL_PORT ?

Adding rules like

```
$IPTABLES -A PREROUTING -t nat -s $INTRANET -p tcp -d $EXTERNAL_IP \
    --dport $EXTERNALPORT -j DNAT --to $INTERNAL_IP:$INTERNAL_PORT
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -s $INTRANET -p tcp -d $INTERNAL_IP \
    --dport $INTERNAL_PORT -j ACCEPT
```

where $INTRANET is CIDR for intranet addresses, doesn't work.

I need to retain source addresses of intranet devices as a result (the target should know the exact origin of connection).

So far, static override for IP in hosts files is used, which is not convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it does not work.

Let us follow for a moment a packet leaving YOUR_PC, going to a Web site with external IP address HTTP_EXT, and internal IP address HTTP_LAN. Let us consider first the **original** iptables rule.

1. Packet leaves YOUR_PC going to HTT_EXT, goes to CentOS router;
2. CentOS router intercepts it, rewrites source address as its own, and sends the packet to HTTP_LAN instead of HTTP_EXT;
3. HTTP_LAN receives the packet, sees it comes form the CentOS, and replies to it;
4. CentOS receives the reply packet, remembers it was part of a conversation that was DNATted, rewrites the reply address as HTTP_EXT instead of HTTP_LAN, sends it to YOUR_PC.
5. YOUR_PC sees a reply packet coming from HTTP_EXT, to which it had written. All's well.

But **now**, consider what happens if you **could** do what you wish to do:

1. Packet leaves YOUR_PC going to HTT_EXT, goes to CentOS router;
2. CentOS router intercepts it, does **not** rewrite source address as its own, and sends the packet to HTTP_LAN instead of HTTP_EXT;
3. HTTP_LAN receives the packet, sees it comes from YOUR_PC, and replies to it, without passing through the CentOS;
4. YOUR_PC receives the packet from HTTP_LAN, while it had written to HTTP_EXT. For obvious security reasons, it will discard the reply packet.

So in this case, *it does not work*, like you said. Stated otherwise: this INTRANET address transformation works **if and only if** you do simultaneously DNAT and SNAT.

Comment: The above (SNAT/DNAT wherever possible)  assumes that all the traffic goes through the router. If devices can connect directly to one another (as usually is) - if I understand correctly - there will be no working technique to redirect traffic as required.

Comment: @KonstantinBoyandin Yes: you cannot maintain the internal LAN address of the packet source. It **must** be changed to the routerìs, so that the reply packet goes back to the router, which again modifies the packet header.